# Get those IDs from a list which are NOT in the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with about 200k unique IDs. Now I want to check a list (3k-10k) of IDs against the table and get thoose IDs from the list which are not in the database (very few).

I coud use:

```
SELECT ids FROM table WHERE ids IN(id1,id2,id3...list_of_IDs_end)
```

But this would give me the IDs from the list which are in the db.

I could do extra programming, but is there a sql only solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try:

```
SELECT ids FROM your_table WHERE ids NOT IN(id1,id2,id3...list of IDs end)
```

If you can, you could put your list in a temporary table and use:

```
SELECT t1.ids
FROM your_table t1 LEFT JOIN temp_table t2
    ON t1.ids = t2.ids
WHERE t2.ids IS NULL
```

Comment: without temporary table is it possible? I want to do same

Comment: @SameerKazi: yes, use my first sample!